# How do I add a blank command?(Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

I am creating a dice bot now and want to create a flexible command. For example, '!1d6'(!XdY).
Also, I want to create a command like '![GAMENAME] [COMMAND]'. For example, '!Cthulhu CBR(50, 20)'(Since there are many game names, adding it manually is difficult.).

Both but are confident that can be achieved in the same way, do not know the way.
I know how to add on_message, but I do not know how to add with @client.command().

Please kindly tell me.

[I used Google Translate.]

Comment: you listen for `on_message` and then parse the message ...

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  # Takes in format dice!xdy i.e dice!3d7 rolls 3 d7 dice
  if (message.content.startswith == 'dice!'):
    await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Rolling...')
    diceArr = message.content[5:].split("d")
    totRolled = 0
    for x in range(int(diceArr[0])):
      totRolled = random.randrange(1, int(diceArr[1]), 1) + totRolled
    await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Rolled', totRolled)
```

This should do it. I've not tested it though as my Linux laptop is dead

Non-Discord version:

```
import random

# Takes in format dice!xdy i.e dice!3d7 rolls 3 d7 dice
def roll(stri):
  print('Rolling...')
  diceArr = stri[5:].split("d")
  totRolled = 0
  for x in range(int(diceArr[0])):
    totRolled = random.randrange(1, int(diceArr[1]), 1) + totRolled
  print('Rolled', str(totRolled))

roll("dice!3d7")
```

Comment: `message.content == 'dice!'` should probably be `message.content.startswith('dice!')`